# How can I install the latest version of PyMca?

Tags: python

The version of PyMca that is packaged with 22.04.1 LTS is an older version (5.7.1+dfsg) that lacks many features of the current version (5.7.6) that I need.  I have tried to manually install the latest version but ran into the error:

```
  /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:551:42: note: declared here
    551 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject*) PyUnicode_FromUnicode(
        |                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
  [end of output
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyMca5

I am looking for any help you can offer and would very much appreciate the packaging of the latest verison of PyMca into 22.04.1 LTS.

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer.

Don

Comment: Any version of an app packaged with the OS or from Ubuntu software has been tested. Any other version you may download and install you are on your own.

Comment: ... and the only way to install the version you want is to download the source code and compile.